# Assembly 8086. Read from the standard input several numbers, in base 2. Print on the screen these numbers in base 10

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So, i have to convert the numbers from base two in base 10, and i have no idea how to do it.This is how my program looks for now, but I am not sure if what I got until now works properly. The conversion part is really giving me a hard time, but for sure I have lots of mistakes in my code, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   assume cs:code, ds:data

data segment
msg db 'Give numbers:$'
numbers LABEL BYTE
    max_size DB 100
    numbers_len DB ?
    number DB 100 dup (?)
ten db 10
errm db 'Numbers not in binary.$'
data ends
code segment
start:

mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset msg
int 21h

mov AH,0Ah
mov DX,offset numbers
int 21h

mov CL,numbers_len
mov CH,0
mov SI,0    
repeat:
    mov AL,number[SI]
    cmp AL,' '
    je conversion

    check:
    cmp AL,'0'
    jb erro
    cmp AL,'1'
    ja erro

    jmp conversion
    continue:
    inc SI
    dec cx
    jcxz print 
    jmp repeat


conversion:

    jmp continue

print:
    pop dx
    add dl,'0'
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
    loop print  
erro:
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset errm
    int 21h

mov ax,4c00h
int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Comment: Okay, and what is the problem you're experiencing? You've broadly stated the desired behaviour and thus output, but you've not made any mention of the supplied input, nor of the output observed. Please, _please_ - don't say "it's not working". Have you stepped through the code with a debugger? Specifically, what is it you need help with?

Comment: it gets into an infinite loop after i give the numbers

Comment: TurboDebugger was always a good debugger for DOS. Anyhow, have a look at the code following the `check:` label. If the digit is too small, nick-off. If the digit is too large, nick off. If the digit is just right (0 or 1) then jmp to `conversion`. At this point, you then jmp straight back to where you would have been, if you never jmped to `conversion.` Hmmmmm?! One of your other problems is thinking that your loop counter, `CX` is untouched during an `int 21h` - it isn't, you should push it first and pop it after. Next, you're poping `dx` in a loop. Has it been pushed this many times first?

Comment: @enhzflep I see int 21h/02h 21h/09h and 21h/0ah. Which one destroys CX, CL or CH? Those particular interrupts to my knowledge don't destroy _CX_.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - indeed. Further checking has revealed that I've incorrectly remembered this. :Hangs head and goes in search of neurons with ECC:

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is not possible to perform base-2 to base-10 conversion directly : you have to convert the base-2 representation into an actual value in a register, and then turn that into base-10. This is because those bases are not related to each other, e.g. there is no way to obtain 10 by applying an integer power to 2.

Here's the code for the conversion from a base-2 string to a number. No error checking is performed, every character that's not `1` is simply treated as `0`.

```
; input : bx - the starting address of the string, cx - its length
; output : ax - contents of the string interpreted as base-2
from_bin:
  mov di, bx
  add di, cx
  sub di, 1
  xor ax, ax
  mov dx, 1

.loop:
  cmp di, bx
  jb .end

  cmp byte [di], '1'
  jne .loop_next

  add ax, dx

.loop_next:
  shl dx, 1
  sub di, 1
  jmp .loop

.end:
  ret
```

As you can see, the code builds up the return value in `ax` by adding `dx` to it if there is a `1` at the current position. `dx` corresponds to the value of 2^n in every iteration of the loop, where `n` is the current position in the string, starting from zero.

The code to convert a value to base-10 uses division to convert the "native" base-2 value stored in a register into consecutive base-10 digits of that value.

```
; input : ax - the number to convert
; di - the last writable address of the output buffer
; output : di - the address of the last written character
; destroys bx, cx, dx
to_dec:
  mov cx, 10

.loop:
  xor dx, dx
  div cx

  mov bx, dx
  or bl, '0'
  mov [di], bl
  test ax, ax
  jz .end

  sub di, 1
  jmp to_dec

.end:
  ret
```

The conversion is done "backwards" : it starts from the lowest position and works its way up as long as the result of the division is nonzero - this means that there is still more to convert. This is also why the function needs to obtain the last writable address of the buffer instead of its beginning.

Comment: `add ax, 1` would save a register; using `mov dx, 1` ahead of the loop seems like obfuscation to me.  (If you want the smaller code-size of avoiding an immediate, use `inc ax`).  Oh, I see you're looping from the LSB (end of the string) instead of the start.  You can `shl ax,1` instead to open up a new space at the bottom of the number you're accumulating.

Comment: Also, `cmp dl, [di]` (with '0' in dl) / `adc ax, ax` will shift in a `1` bit (from '0'-'1' producing a borrow) or a `0` bit (from them being equal), so you can avoid the separate `shl ax,1`