# How to add two binary inputs in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, binary, addition, masm

I want the program to take to inputs. Both 8 characters long that can either be 0 or 1, and end when hitting enter. Than the values should be added and displayed in decimal form. I have a base for the program that takes and writes one (any) character so far. I'm new to assembly programming, I'm using MASM611 and I want to achieve this WITHOUT using the data segment.

```
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK

.CODE
main proc

main endp

CR EQU 13
LF EQU 10

cr_lf proc
    PUSH DX
    MOV DL, CR
    CALL write_char
    MOV DL, LF
    CALL write_char
    POP DX
    RET
cr_lf endp

read_char proc
    PUSH AX
    MOV AH, 1
    INT 21h
    MOV DL, AL
    POP AX
    RET
read_char endp

write_char proc
    PUSH AX
    MOV AH, 2
    INT 21h
    POP AX
    RET
write_char endp
```

I wanted to go about this where the input gets stored in a register, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Again, I'm new, but please if you can, provide a solution, rather than an explanation so I can see how it works.

Comment: Base 2 input doesn't need any extra space, just a register you shift and add (or OR) into, or `adc bx, bx` after getting the bit you want into CF.  Base 10 output ([Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075)) can only generate digits least-significant first, so you'd normally need some memory, but it could just be stack space, either with push/pop to reverse or just a buffer you store bytes into in reverse order.  Or since 3 digits is the maximum, you could use just registers.

Comment: Near duplicate of [Assembly 8086. Read from the standard input several numbers, in base 2. Print on the screen these numbers in base 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34384754) - the answer uses pointers to buffers, but they can be in stack space.  Or you can slightly adapt the code especially for input to read input inside the conversion loop, instead of a string you already input.