# How to ask for multiple character long input in MASM611?

Tags: assembly, binary, masm

I'm new to assembly and I'm having trouble solving this exercise: Ask for two binary numbers as input, then perform an AND operation on them and write the result to the screen. I can't even begin to solve it, hence the title. I'm not allowed to use the data segment either. Some of the subroutines I have are these, I'm supposed to expand upon them:

```
read_char proc 
PUSH AX 
MOV AH, 1 
INT 21h 
MOV DL, AL
POP AX 
RET 
read_char endp

write_char proc 
PUSH AX 
MOV AH, 2 
INT 21h 
POP AX 
RET
write_char endp
```

These only take one character as far as I know. If you could provide a full solution, that would be the best for understanding the functionality.

Comment: Call read_char in a loop, and `shr dl, 1` / `adc bx, bx` to transfer the bit the bottom of DL to CF, then shift it into the bottom of BX.  (implementing `total = total*2 + digit` in a way that takes advantage of computers already being binary.)

Comment: [Assembly 8086. Read from the standard input several numbers, in base 2. Print on the screen these numbers in base 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34384754) shows one way of reading base-2 input in printing order.  Replace the load with a read_char call.  But it's written inefficiently to use more registers than needed.